# Android studio: How to use forked library in XML?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, github

I am trying to use a forked version of the PhotoView library and I cannot seem to find a way to use its tag in my XML, any ideas?

(im new to android studio)

Original tag:

```
<com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView/>
```

My fork:https://github.com/regiregi2/PhotoView

dependency: `implementation 'com.github.regiregi2:PhotoView:master-SNAPSHOT'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just have refactor package name `com.github.chrisbanes.photoview` to `com.github.regiregi2.photoview` and then to use it's absolute class-name:

```
<com.github.regiregi2.photoview.PhotoView />
```

unless refactoring, the absolute class-name would still be:

```
<com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView/>
```

Comment: I have tried that and when i launch the activity with the tag in it the app crashes

Comment: @Richard8365 see https://jitpack.io/docs/ the syntax is `com.github.User:Repo:Version`... which does not affect the package-name, unless it had been refactored. therefore properly refactoring in order to have dependency and package names matching is suggested.

Comment: ok thanks, i have deleted and import from the original and it fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your root build.gradle file (not your module build.gradle file):

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

}

Then, add the library to your module build.gradle

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:latest.release.here'
```

}

Comment: Thats for the original library, i have'nt updated the readme yet